# Disable function loading xml in swf

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

So i have swf file witch is loading data from XML. I have function for loading the first `node` and function to load the second `node`. Everything is working fine but when i load the second function and after that load again the first one. Some data from the second is staying in some of the fields.

```
var my_xml = new XML();
my_xml.ignoreWhite = true;
my_xml.onLoad = onXMLLoaded;
function reloadXML(){ 
my_xml.load("direktno.xml");
}
my_xml.load("direktno.xml");



function onXMLLoaded() { }
function mach() { }
```

Any ideas how to delete or block the second function and after that block the firs when im loading the second ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Why you cant try some thing like this, load the first xml file on loadcomplete of the load the next, before loading the next xml file, use one boolean value to resist the further loading, and also instantiate two different xml variables

Comment: @rajesh.adhi I have only one Xml file with two nodes! And can you put with code please ?

Comment: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/xml/  check out this

Comment: Why do you load two nodes separately? ActionScript has tools for working with XML so that you can select specific nodes from an XML tree based on name, index, etc.

Comment: Because I'm showing the results from both nodes in the same frame with a switch button. So when I'm switching to the second node it works but some of the fields witch are field in the first node stays in the second ! So the thing is that i have to remove all loaded data from the first node and then loads the second !

Answer (score 0):

You can just give a condition for loading the function, eg. when the XML loads, execute first function like that so etc.